# Split screen running Windows 8 on MacBook Air

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, mac, windows-8-preview

I've installed Windows 8 Developer Preview 32 Bit view Boot-Camp on my MacBook Air 13" Mid 2011.

When the installation is finishes and Windows boots up for the first time, the screen splits and I can only see one half twice.

[image: MacBookAir with Windows 8]

Any Solutions?

Comment: would suspect a graphics driver issue, very interesting symptom.

Comment: Funny thing is: It worked for 2minutes, but after logging out, it got this behavior. When i attach another display via VGA-Adapter, i can see the screen on the other display correct

Comment: But it is an Intel HD 3000 "graphics card", so i think there shouldn't be a driver issue

Comment: … wait for the final release? Even if the chipset is HD 3000 it still could be a driver thing. Who knows, that's why it's called "developer preview".